# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka send message

Tags: spring-boot, functional-programming, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

How can i send a message with the new Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Functional Model?

The deprecated way looked like this.

```java
public interface OutputTopic {

    @Output("output")
    MessageChannel output();
}

@Autowired
OutputTopic outputTopic;

public someMethod() {
    
    outputTopic.output().send(MessageBuilder.build());
}
```

But how can i send a message in the functional style?

application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: process
    stream:
      bindings:
        process-out-0:
          destination: output
          binder: kafka
```

```java
@Configuration
public class Configuration {

    @Bean
    Supplier<Message<String>> process() {
        return () -> {
            return MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo")
                    .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "bar".getBytes()).build();
        };
    }
```

I would Autowire a MessageChannel but there is no MessageChannel-Bean for process, process-out-0, output or something like that. Or can i send a message with a Supplier-Bean?
Could someone please give me an example?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use the `StreamBridge` or the reactor API - see [Sending arbitrary data to an output (e.g. Foreign event-driven sources)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources)

Comment: The EmitterProcessor is deprected. Do you know the newest way to use it?

Comment: The `StreamBridge` as Gary mentioned is the recommended way. We'll update the docs to remove any references to `EmitterProcessor`,